# How to put picture into glossary entry?

Tags: diagrams, glossaries

I'm using the Glossaries package, which is fantastic, but I'd like to put in pictures which explain the term better than words would. Is there a way for me to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

Code (replace with your own images or use `demo` option for `graphicx`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=long,nopostdot,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newglossaryentry{res}{%
    name={Resistor},
    description={\protect\fbox{\protect\includegraphics[width=1cm]{resistor}}}
}
\newglossaryentry{cap}{%
    name={Capacitor},
    description={\protect\fbox{\protect\includegraphics[width=1cm]{capacitor}}}
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary
\end{document}
```